# Extending div element's width past Bootstrap's container class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap's container class has a width of 1170px which is great for display information, but I want my footer background to extend to the edges of the page, no matter what the screen size is.  I've seen solutions suggesting I set a width of 2000px, but I would prefer a cleaner solution in case somebody is using a monitor with a large screen width.  I also don't want to override Bootstrap's container class' width because that would mess up positioning of my elements.

Is there a way in CSS to tell a background to spill out past it's containing div?

**Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfMtX/2/)**

Here is my current `.footer` class which is being bound by Bootstrap's `.container` class:

```
.footer {
    float: left;
    background: #000;
    margin-top:40px;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you can recreate the issue on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @Shouvik added a fiddle for you

Comment: I don't get it, is the `important` not solving your problem? Made some more edits on the class. Check if that solves the problem.

Comment: `width:100%` on a child element will (at most) make it 100% of its' parent (1170 wide, which is too small)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your design a little

```
    <!-- .footer's old home -->
    </container>
    <footer>
        <container>Your previous footer kids</container>
    </footer>
</body>
```

`.container` is a class, so it can have multiple occurrences.

Actually, I would bet that's why Bootstrap made .container a class, and NOT an id in the first place.

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V7Yyf/

BTW - `.container` has a width of 'auto' at certain viewport sizes (see: line #825 of bootstrap-responsive.css)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.footer {
    float: left;
    background: #000;
    margin-top:40px;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: -83px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

The `!important` option basically takes priority over any other property which may be overwriting it.

Also edit on container class in bootstrap.css

```
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  *zoom: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100% !important;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: the `position: absolute` helped extend the footer, but only on the right side which is a start.  when i add `margin-left:-83px` it messes up the alignment of all my elements inside my `.footer` which is why i don't want to use that.

Comment: hmm, so make the elements inside relative? Don't extend the property to the children. Hopefully they may be using a different class, else create one whose sole aim is to make the position of them relative to the footer. PS: updated fiddle link please

Comment: okay never mind. I guess it's 2. Well anyway, you need to add some more child elements whose alignments is getting messed up. Only then can I understand how your structure is getting affected.

Comment: Mind you, this is not the most elegant solution, but because it works, it's acceptable. I would suggest going back to the drawing board and making stuff relative. I am not a fan of absolutes or constant px's...